# Local Port for network printer

Tags: windows-services, network-printer

I want to use a local port/ tcpip port for my network printer. But so far, have managed to set it up, but no matter what I did, was unable to even do a test print.

below are my steps:
1)Local Port-

Add Printer
Choose local printer, deselect plug and play
create new local port
port name: testing
Choose driver
Printer name: test
No share.

2)TCPIP Port-
choose TCPIP standard port.
Filled in IPAddress/ HostName (tried both)
--I'm stuck here.
Using pos printer(Bematech MP-400TH but no field for me to select) (for Espon TM-T88IV, i choose Epson Network Printer).
For my Bematech printer, I'm not sure how to continue, for Epson printer,I clicked next and finish. It prompt me for driver. Already installed on computer but the model doesn't show up in the selection.  Clicked have disk and browse to C:\Program Files\EPSON\TMUSB\Win2KXP and point to the inf file.
It then prompt me with an error "The specified location does not contain information about your hardware"

Hope someone will be able to help. Need local / TCPIP port for printing using Window Service. Tried with all account type also can't help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ping the network address you're pointing to to make sure that's what the printer is set to? If it's a network printer, it should have a diagnostic/status page or display where it tells you the current network config.

If you have the driver decompressed on the system you should be able to just browse to the folder and let it pull the correct information from the .INI file, if the printer is being seen properly.

I'd first verify the printer is seeing the network properly, then work on the driver.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have no issue using the same network and hardware to do a normal network printing. ie: to browse network for printers, able to do test print. I'm very amateur when it comes to network, so I'm also stuck in troubleshooting.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to allow window service to print onto network printer, a normal win32 program do just fine, but if i change to a service, it cannot detect network printers, hence came to this option

Comment: I guess I miss what you're doing with the service vs. windows printing. You're trying to share it to other computers via a Windows system vs. the printer acting as a network device?

Comment: not really a this vs that, but more of solution to make window service act as a central printing server which will print out to the correct printer correctly. Saw alot of people managed to make use of Local port like http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/how-to-install-a-network-printer-on-your-home-or-office-network/. So I believe if I can achieve this step, it should be fine

Comment: There's no windows service involved. First get the computer to see the printer; verify the IP address on the printer (should be *static*) and check that Windows can ping it.

Comment: Then set up Windows to add the "local" tcp/ip port to print to. Make sure you download the latest drivers for that printer so you can add the proper driver.

Comment: After you can print from the Windows machine, you configure *sharing*. Then you have a print server. There's no service involved. You can point other computers to the windows machine that has it added as a local printer (the print server) and that machine will in turn dole out print jobs.

Comment: that the part that puzzle me, I have configured it in a way I share my printer. Ok for instance my com is 10.10.10.10 with printer connected to USB. Another com 10.10.10.11 connects to my printer using add network printer. This way it can print. however if I use 10.10.10.11 to connect to my com using local port/ tcpip port, it seems successful, the printer status is ready, but I will never be able to print at all.

Comment: In one, print job goes to computer goes to printer. In the other, print job goes directly to the printer. And in your "however" you didn't specify the printers IP address. Did you ever verify the printer's IP address? I think that's been asked a few times...

Comment: And You *don't* connect as an IP printer from computer to computer. Your PRINTER needs the IP address. You can't use a USB-only connected printer as an IP printer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the latest driver from the Bematech website?

http://www.bematech.com/en/products/prod_pos_mp4000th.asp

The driver is the first on the list but it looks like most of them are executables. In your case, you might need to use a program to extract the latest driver from the executable such as 7zip and then when the Windows wizard prompts you to select a driver, point it to the folder where you extracted it. As Bart indicated, you are looking for an ini file.

Also, just because the name doesn't quite match doesn't mean you have the wrong driver. Some of the drivers released are similar for products of the same line.

*"What I want to achieve is to allow window service to print onto network printer, a normal win32 program do just fine, but if i change to a service, it cannot detect network printers, hence came to this option"* --> I am not sure what you mean by this. Windows service to print to network printer? Please explain. The only service involved is the spooler but you shouldn't have to mess with that at all.

Also, is your connection correct? How is the printer connected to the computer? Via a router?

Comment: The driver I'm using is already working, like my comment to Bart Silverstrim's , adding that printer as a network printer allows me to print, adding it as a local printer gives me problem. will try to download the newest driver and test again